# Bootstrap 3 modal not working correctly when placed inside a fixed parent

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm attempting to launch a form from the header of a website I'm designing, using a Bootstrap 3 modal window. Here's the link; the modal should launch from 'email signup':

http://pamaphilly.wpengine.com/

The issue is that the 'fixed logo ribbon' should be a persistent and fixed element at the top of the page. When I use fixed positioning, though, the modal doesn't work correctly. However, if I removed fixed positioning, it functions as expected. See this video: http://screencast.com/t/LeFCDXuf0GrE

The CSS class I'm changing is:

```
.fixed-logo-ribbon {
    background-color: #e41535;
    height: 4.75em;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 5em;
    top: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Also, the html is just the standard modal demo:

```
<div class="fixed-logo-ribbon">
  <div class="container logo-container">
    <a href="http://pamaphilly.wpengine.com/">
      <img class=logo-PAMA type="image/svg+xml" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/PAMA-logo-2014-masthead.svg" height="40" width="360" alt="PAMA-logo">
    </a><!-- end logo div -->
   <div class="social-media-icons pull-right">
     <div class="join-us less-margin">
       <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Join the AMA Now" class="join-link" target="_blank" href="http://www.jointheama.com/">join now</a>
     </div>
     <!-- Button trigger modal -->
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg join-us" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
       Launch demo modal
     </button>
     <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get the modal to work while still having a fixed header, as intended?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Per the official docs:

> ### [Modal markup placement](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
>
> **Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document** to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

Your mistake is also known as [Bootlint problem ID `E022`](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E022).

The fix is move the `<div class="modal ...">...</div>` so that it's a direct child of the `<body>`, rather than being a descendant of the navbar.

Comment: What a lifesaver and so easy to fix... Thanks so much for the help.
Now I know.

Comment: Update:Well, I think I am once again at my wit's end... I moved the modal such that it is a direct child of the body tag. The problem is I still need it to be fixed, since, at least visually, it will need to appear to be part of the other header elements. It also needs to stay relative to the other elements in the header, as browser gets rezized. Whenever I apply 'fixed' though, the modal breaks. So, frankly, it seems as though this issue is as much related to an aversion of the modal to the use of fixed positioning as it is a matter of where in the document flow it is launched from.